# Python Wordcloud from a txt file

Tags: python, word-cloud

I'm trying to create a wordcloud using text from a txt file.

so far this is the code i have

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS


file_content=open ("tweets.txt").read()



wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path = 'C:\Windows\Fonts\Verdana.tff',
                            stopwords=STOPWORDS,
                            background_color = 'white',
                            width=1200,
                            height=1000
                            ).generate(file_content)

plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

the error that is show after i run this code is :

```
 File "WordCloud.py", line 14, in <module>
    ).generate(file_content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py", line 448, in generate
    return self.generate_from_text(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py", line 434, in generate_from_text
    self.generate_from_frequencies(words)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py", line 317, in generate_from_frequencies
    font = ImageFont.truetype(self.font_path, font_size)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 238, in truetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.font = core.getfont(font, size, index, encoding)
IOError: cannot open resource
```

BONUS question: how to change the text colour?

Comment: Give us a sample of the `tweets.txt` file.

Comment: I think it should be Verdana.ttf not .tff

Comment: It complains of missing font file. 'Cannot open resource'

Comment: If it works after changing from .tff to .ttf, I'm voting to close this as a simple typographical error.

Comment: damn, sorry guys it works after changing the font extension, am so stupid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, change your font to `ttf` but I recommend you also prefix it with `r` to avoid any accidental escaping with the backslashes.

To add your own colour scheme, you need to add a colour callback function, e.g. `random_color_func`. This one builds a HSL type colour with random L and fixed H and S.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS


def random_color_func(word=None, font_size=None, position=None, orientation=None, font_path=None, random_state=None):
    h = int(360.0 * 45.0 / 255.0)
    s = int(100.0 * 255.0 / 255.0)
    l = int(100.0 * float(random_state.randint(60, 120)) / 255.0)

    return "hsl({}, {}%, {}%)".format(h, s, l)

file_content=open ("tweets.txt").read()

wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path = r'C:\Windows\Fonts\Verdana.ttf',
                            stopwords = STOPWORDS,
                            background_color = 'white',
                            width = 1200,
                            height = 1000,
                            color_func = random_color_func
                            ).generate(file_content)

plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```